# Browser Back Event without onbeforeunload and unload events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on payment flow, when user clicks browser back need to Custom POP UP confirmation box with two links one to redirect to different page and second to same page in Javascript or Jquery. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

This might help you (although it's not best practice to interfere with browser controls): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: Thanks Joris, but i can't use onbeforeunload  because when user clicks "OK" or "Leave This Page" user as to redirect to different page.

Comment: Joris, really i don't have solution, i tried with onbeforeunload, unload and history.go nothing works. My main problem is changing the click on "OK" or "Leave this Page". window.onbeforeunload = function () {
          if(confirm("Please Confirm")) {
            //Redirect to different page eg
               window.location.href='http://m.google.com';
          }else {
                 // Stop
          }
   }

Comment: Joris, Can you please on this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'the click'? Which click? On what moment? On what object? Can you please post the code you've used to test unload()? Try to be as clear and illustrative as possible in your questions.