# Prevent location.back() outside application Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I wrote PageNotFound component for my app and add link here "Go Back" but if history is empty I want to redirect user on main page "/".

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-not-found',
    templateUrl: './app/error/page-not-found/page-not-found.component.html'
})
export class PageNotFoundComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private titleService: Title,
        private location: Location) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.titleService.setTitle('Page Not Found');
    }

    back() {
        //check if history is empty somehow and execute 'this.router.navigate["/"];'
        this.location.back();
    }
}
```

How can I implement that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784814/browser-back-event-without-onbeforeunload-and-unload-events

Comment: First of all, You cant control anything outside of your app.  And you can use `router.navigate` instead of `location.back` which means this all stay within ur application.

Comment: How do you suggest to use `router.navigate`? Always redirect on main page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it in the following way:

```
back() {
        if (window.history.length > 1) {
            this.location.back();
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only works if you didn't visit another side before.